# Is it possible to give away a apple content subscription code?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, subscription

I know that as a developer you can give away codes so that users can download your app for free. Is it possible to do the same for a subscription to content within an app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible with in-app purchases, you have codes only for download apps.